# How to display more than one time in JavaScript using for loop

Tags: javascript

I was learning JS From W3 schools and encounter this program which checks the attribute length. I later modified it to display name of attribute that an element has. Here is the code

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
    var a = document.getElementById("myBtn").attributes[counter].name;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>Click the button to see how many attributes the button element have.</p>
  <p id="output">

  </p>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected O/P to be as :

> id onclick

But for some reason it only display the last attribute that an element holds in this case its **onclick** if it were *class* or something else it would have displayed that.

Whats the reason for that ?

Comment: you are runnig loop its getting overwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very simple mistake in your code. Your code will first set the innerHTML of the `<p>` element to "id". Then, it will overwrite it with the next attribute, i.e. "onclick". To fix this, change

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = a
```

to

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += a + "<br>"
```

The `<br>` is just to seperate the attributes from each other. Here is the whole snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    var a = document.getElementById("myBtn").attributes[counter].name;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += a + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>Click the button to see how many attributes the button element have.</p>
  <p id="output">

  </p>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below instead

```
function myFunction() {
var a="";
  for (var counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++){
     a+= document.getElementById("myBtn").attributes[counter].name;
}
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Your code displays the last value set to a. And you do not append / add the names of the attributes to a, instead you overwrite a with

```
var a = ....
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are re-assigning `a` each time the loop runs (`var a = ...`):

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    var a = document.getElementById("myBtn").attributes[counter].name;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = a;
}
```

This means that `a` ends up being the last item.

Perhaps instead, add each attribute to an array:

```
function myFunction() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    arr.push(document.getElementById("myBtn").attributes[counter].name);
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
}
```

Also, use curly braces for where your scopes are.  You want that `output` to be *after* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you change the innerHTML of the element, which means you change the whole HTML of that element.

To do what you want, you could concatenate the results on the current innerHTML or create elements and add the values inside of them, then append them to the document.

For example:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + ' - ' + a;
```